# Add new property to a class at runtime using reflection

Tags: c#

I have some serialized data (using BinaryFormatter), and wanting to deserialise it. However the deserialise method failed since the current assembly does not have the deleted field. I want to be able to reconstruct earlier assembly at run-time in order to deserialise the data. Appreciated any pointer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the technique is called versiontolerant serialization
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752.aspx